# Using ggpattern to create bar graphs using images

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I'd like to create a ggplot bar graph, using my own photos to fill the bars.
I've tried using ggpattern to do this, however I am having trouble.
What is the best way to load the chosen .jpeg photos into R, and how should they be incorporated into the bar plot?

Answer (score 1):

`ggpattern` is a good bet, but you could also use `ggtextures`. If for some reason, your image files are not working with either library, try converting images to another format. If you want to stay fully within R, convert your files with the `magick` library.

Since you didn't provide example data, I'm adding a random example you can run. I use `magick` to load and crop images that are then saved locally as PNG images. Then a `ggpattern::geom_col_pattern()` is added into a `ggplot()` to fill the bar chart with images. The parameters within ggppatern "geoms" are highly configurable.

```
 #This R script demonstrates use of the library ggpattern to add image textures to visualizations + magick to edit image files
    library(ggpattern) #remotes::install_github("coolbutuseless/ggpattern")
    library(ggplot2)
    library(magick)
    library(tibble)
    library(dplyr)
    #create data to visualize
    cakes<-tibble( cake_name=c("Chocolate Cake","Cream Cake ","Pound Cake",
                        "White or Yellow Cake","Devil’s Food Cake",
                        "Sponge Cake","Angel Food Cake","Water"),
            gravity = c(.9,.85,.8,.7,.7,.5,.3,1)) %>%
            dplyr::arrange(-.$gravity)
    #Get images to use as textures. Edit using magick library
    cake_img<-magick::image_read_svg(c("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/49/Cartoon_Happy_Birthday_Cake.svg"))%>%
      magick::image_rotate(., 90) %>%image_crop(., "725x600+50+75")
    water_img<-image_read_svg('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/06/Water_compartment.svg') %>%image_crop(., "500x250+150")
    #save edited images locally
    magick::image_write(cake_img, path = "cake.png", format = "png")
    magick::image_write(water_img, path = "water.png", format = "png")
    #Create a vector of filepaths to the images that will be used
    n_cake_img<-list.files(pattern = 'cake.png',full.names=TRUE) %>% rep(.,nrow(cakes)-1)
#The vector of image paths is same length as data to be visualized.
img_paths<-c(n_cake_img, list.files(pattern = 'water.png',full.names=TRUE))
    
    #plot the data with images as background.           
    p <- ggplot(cakes)+ 
      geom_col_pattern( aes(reorder(cake_name,gravity), 
                            gravity, pattern_filename =reorder(cake_name,gravity)),
        pattern = 'image',
        pattern_fill="white",
        fill="white",
        pattern_type = 'expand',
        pattern_aspect_ratio = 1) +
         theme_bw(18) +
      xlab("", size=12)+
      theme(legend.position = 'none') +
      scale_pattern_filename_discrete(choices = img_paths)+
      coord_flip()
    #add labeling
    p +
      labs(title = "Optimal Specific Gravity of Cake Batters",
           subtitle = "Ratio of batter weight & room temperature water of the same volume.",
           caption = "Data source: https://bakerpedia.com/processes/specific-gravity-cakes/
    Image credit(s): https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Water_compartment.svg
    https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/49/Cartoon_Happy_Birthday_Cake.svg")+
      theme(
      plot.title = element_text(color = "Black", size = 32, face = "bold"),
      plot.subtitle = element_text(color = "darkgrey", size = 14),
      plot.caption = element_text(color = "grey",size = 11, face = "italic"),
      axis.title.x = element_text(size = 20),
      axis.text.y=element_text(size=rel(1.5))
    )
```

[image: ggpattern visualization example showing specific gravity of cakes]

As you can see, `ggpattern::geom_col_pattern()` just references the image file path, so you don't really load the image as an R object ahead of plotting.

Here is a simplified example of converting image files in `magick` library in case that is useful.

```
your_img<-magick::image_read("yourfile.jpeg")
your_new_img<-magick::image_write(your_img, path = "newfile.png", format = "png")
```